# How do I use an array of values to limit a for loop in perl?

Tags: arrays, perl, for-loop

The question is rather vague I know, but I hope the space to explain may help shed light, this is something I've wracked my brain around all day and couldn't find any advice through searching.

Basically I have an array @cluster that I'm trying to use to make an iterator $x skip over the values located in that array. The array will vary in size, so I can't just (rather atrociously) make if statements to fit all cases unfortunately.

Normally when I need to do this with a scalar value I just do:

```
for my $x (0 .. $numLines){
    if($x != $value){
        ...
    }
}
```

Any advice?

Comment: do you mean something like `for my $x(@cluster)`?

Comment: Quite the opposite. I want any value in @cluster to not be used.
I suppose I could use another for loop like `for my $y(@cluster)` within my current for $x loop.

Comment: How do you know the values you want to skip?  Is it that it equals a particular value or is the n value processed?

Comment: It equals any value located in @cluster.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do:

```
my @cluster = (1,3,4,7);
outer: for my $x (0 .. 10){
    $x eq $_ and next outer for @cluster;
    print $x, "\n";
}
```

With Perl 5.10 you can also do:

```
for my $x (0 .. 10){
    next if $x ~~ @cluster;
    print $x, "\n";
}
```

or better to use a hash:

```
my @cluster = (1,3,4,7);
my %cluster = map {$_, 1} @cluster;
for my $x (0 .. 10){
    next if $cluster{$x};
    print $x, "\n";
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I was secretly hoping I would have an excuse to use a hash, I haven't had one in a long time. Many many thanks!

Comment: it's strange writing Perl and not using hashes :)

Comment: I'm unfortunately a Perl beginner but the hash type is so fascinatingly fun to me I've been trying to put it in everything I do, but currently the work I have is rather straightforward.

Comment: @SirLulzalot How could you not have a reason in a ***long*** time when you are a beginner?

Comment: Long in consideration to my life in Perl XD

Answer (score 2):

Hmm... If you are skipping over lines, why not use that criteria directly instead of remembering the lines that need to be filtered out?

The [`grep`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/grep.html) function is a powerful construct for filtering lists:

```
my @array = 1 .. 10;

print "$_\n" for grep { not /^[1347]$/ } @array;  # 2,5,6,8,9,10
print "$_\n" for grep {     $_ % 2     } @array;  # 1,3,5,7,9

my @text = qw( the cat sat on the mat );

print "$_\n" for grep { ! /at/ } @text;           # the, on, the
```

Much less clutter, and much more DWIM!

Comment: Hmm, I haven't actually implemented anything using Perl's grep function, it was all over my studies in bash, but here I never thought about it. I'll consider it for future attempts, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Dou you mean something like that:

```
for my $x (0 .. $numLines){
    my $is_not_in_claster = 1;
    for( @claster ){
         if( $x == $_ ){
             $is_not_in_claster = 0;
             last;
         }
    }
    if( $is_not_in_claster ){
        ...
    }
}
```

?

Comment: Yeah this does the job, I was hoping perl had something a bit more elegant, but it is a rather complex logic statement, thanks!

Comment: Note that this solution has to loop over `@claster` for each `$x`, which will make it exponentially slower as `$numLines` and `@claster` grow.